# How to double the amplitude of an AC Signal

Tags: voltage, ac, gain, phase-shift, amplitude

If I have an input signal, \$v_{in} = A\sin(2 \pi ft)\$, and I am wanting to double the signal's amplitude so that my output then becomes \$v_{out} = 2A\sin(2 \pi ft + \theta)\$, how might one achieve this using eletrical circuit components?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about using a 1:2 transformer?

Comment: at what frequency, how small is acceptable for theta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. An op-amp non-inverting amplifier. Source: [ECE Tutorials](http://ecetutorials.com/analog-electronics/inverting-and-non-inverting-amplifiers/).*

If your signal is withing +/- 5 V you can use a standard op-amp non-inverting amplifier powered from +/- 15 V supply.

Unfortunately you haven't supplied any details on voltage or frequency range.

Comment: Hi there! Just edited my original post. The voltage range is: 1 < A < 4V in my original vin equation, and 20 < f < 20 kHz for the frequency range :)

Comment: Then you're fine. That would be no problem to most operational amplifiers and you won't have any phase-shift problems. A little web research will give you plenty of designs. Make sure you add the decoupling capacitors to the supply pins to minimise noise. I've added a link to the article the illustration came from.